# openEAR - Introducing the Munich Open-Source Emotion and Affect Recognition Toolkit

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am very new in Android programming and I would like to create an application about emotion recognition from speech. As I am researching I have found out that openEAR - Introducing the Munich Open-Source Emotion and Affect Recognition Toolkit is a good toolkit for this kind of project. But my only problem right now is how am I going to implement toolkit in Android. I don't know how to use toolkit. Before I forgot I have read that OpenEar is written in C++, is it possible to still implement it in Android wherein I used Java? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to still implement it in Android wherein I used Java?

Yes, you need to create a wrapper using Android NDK (native code development kit). See for details

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: thank you for your reply Nikolay. I have now created a wrapper using NDK and its now working, I also installed cygwin to make this work.But right now, my problem is I don't have any idea how the openEAR toolkit will be implemented. Do you know any tutorial links which can lead me on implementation of openEAR? thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what do you mean by "implemented". Please explain better what do you need.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry about that. What I mean is how can I apply the openEAR toolkit in Android in order for me to create an emotion recognition from speech application. I refer to this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openart/ for the openEAR.

Comment: I'm sorry for a noob question, please bear with me. Thanks again

Comment: There is a tutorial for OpenEAR inside source in doc subfolder. Check it out.

Comment: Ah yes, I have already checked it and followed the instructions but still I can't make it work. Maybe, it's complicated for a beginner like me to understand what it states in the tutorial they provided. Hmm.. if you don't mind can I ask another question? Aside from openEAR, do you still have other ideas and sources I can use to make an emotion recognition from speech?